# What is the command to reset Windows to a new-user state?

Tags: windows-7, setup

I used to know how to do this, back when my MCSA/MCSE was still current. For the life of me, I can't recall how though. I know there is a way to rearm the new-user portion of Windows so that, once I get the software and updates all installed, the end user is prompted for a name & password on their first boot.

Comment: I guess you're referring to [sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Looks like I am, thanks. It's amazing how fast we lose sysadmin skills, isn't it? I guess my front end stuff would go just as fast if I let it atrophy though.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to execute sysprep on a running install, vs. building an image and pushing it out.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is quite what I wanted. I seem to recall there being a way to throw a few registry switches and, bam, the new-user prompt came up on boot. It was especially useful in small offices (non AD) where maintaining a sysprep'd image would be overkill - but attorneys still wanted the DIY new user experience.

Comment: Man, I remember it was a real gem when I found the feature - and it was an accidental discovery when I was slipstreaming an XP install.

Comment: I spend many days a week creating and deploying Windows 7 imagesand using sysprep. I would strongly suggest you don't rely on sysprepping already OOBE'd machines to give to a new user. You will reach a point where it won't work or won't be a viable solution. You should create an image the "official" way and sysprep that with OOBE. Deploy the image and OOBE will go through the new user setup. You should use WAIK and DISM to build your image... You can have an "update" image in WIM format so you don't need to keep deploying and capturing... It is much easier now.

Comment: @Imperative The more I think about it, the more it looks like you were using some unsupported hack. I did some research on the matter and found an [interesting thread](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/17549-odd-question-in-unattended/). For what is worth, I was able to get [this screen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xS2K.png) after running a few commands and restarting: http://pastebin.com/EtArqUuE Still, it's not a true out-of-box experience.